# Transformar árvore filogenética em 'phyDat' no R

Tags: r

Alguém sabe como transformar uma árvore filogenética, que está no formato 'txt' para 'phyDat', no R?

Comment: Arthur, não conheço o formato de uma árvore filogenética em `txt` . Você poderia editar a sua pergunta incluindo um exemplo de árvore? Assim é mais fácil de alguém conseguir ajudar.